Issue with Django API Authentication Using Azure AD and Postman
I have set up a django project using the django_auth_adfs library to use the Azure Active Directory for the authentication phase. I have set up its API using rest_framework and now, I am trying to send requests to it using Postman. My problem is that if I send a request with or without an access token, my result is nothing but the raw html code of the Microsoft login page. I used this link for generating my access token:
https://dev.to/425show/calling-an-azure-ad-secured-api-with-postman-22co
I tried different API Permissions for my Azure App such as Azure Active Directory Graph, Microsoft Graph, and one under my own project name which comes from the one I configured as a scope in the Expose an API. Also I wonder if the company should grant access to the api I configured in the Expose an API?
This is the Result I get and this is my postman environment. During the token registration, I am prompt to login using my username, password, and the authentication code sent to my phone, and then, the token is generated successfully. However, I am still getting the login page, although I am using the token in my headers. Also about the django ad configuration, it works fine. People can login and logout using their Microsoft accounts, so the problem should not be there.

Steps to authenticating  Django API using Azure Active Directory (AD) and accessing it via Postman.
Create an application in  App registrations of Microsoft Entra ID.Choose Supported account types as Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant and personal Microsoft accounts  for api.

Add a scope in  Expose an API by selecting consent as   Admins and users  as shown in the below image.


Use Instance ,ClientId and TenantId  in Django API .
 "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
 "ClientId": "18", //Application (Client) ID from 'Catalogue.Api' app registration overview blade
 "TenantId": "932" // Tenant ID from '.Catalogue.Api' app registration overview blade


Create a another application in  Microsoft Entra ID for postman with below callback  url

https://www.postman.com/oauth2/callback

Select Access tokens ,ID tokens in  Authentication  and save it.

In  postman application  add API permissions for Api app which you have created.

Select Delegated permissions and Permissions of api and add permission.


Add a client secret in Postman app.



Create a new Environment  with unique name and add variables, Initial values and current values as shown in the below images .




Replace the values of  productAPiURl of Django API ,callbackurl,clientid,tenantld,scope and clientSecret.



Create a new request and select the Auth Type as  OAuth 2.0 .

Change Callback URL ,Auth URL ,Access Token URL ,Client ID ,Client Secret ,Scope and State  with    Postman app details



  Callback URL:  {{callbackUrl}}
  Auth URL:  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantid}}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
  Token URL : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenantid}}/oauth2/v2.0/token
  Client ID :  {{clientId}}
  Client Secret :  {{clientSecret}}
  Scope:  {{scope}}


Click on Get New Acccess token to sign in and genereate the new token.




Use the token in headers as key name with Authorization .


Replace the  Django API  Url and send the request.


I did everything step by step (except choosing the support type as single tenant, organization directory for my main project as it is for my organization), I was prompt to login after tapping Get New Access Token, which indicates it is referring to the correct Azure app, and it shows up as Authorization in my Headers. But again, I get the sign in to your account html code. My API Permission is granted for the company,  Is it possible that I am missing a permission? Also, check my question again please as I added some screenshot of what I am getting (3rd paragraph). Thank you for your help!

Permissions should include at least User.Read  and any custom permissions defined in your API (Expose an API).

Hi @Sampath, Here are my permissions. I also tried doing it using curl and I got the same problem. I put it here

The post/get request is working fine with postman api with azure active directory and You confirmed sign in  page in addition to post request with Azure active directory. It total different different than compared . As  post request with ad is slove. I will address the remaining issue in the new question you have raised.

Hi Naveen, indeed it is beneficial, but I am still getting the Microsoft login page. @Sampath you are right, I don't think there is anything left in the postman and Azure configurations. It might have raised from my Django REST configuration. Thank you for your help. I accepted your answer.
